# RestSharp Async

Tags: c#, asynchronous, restsharp

I am trying to execute an async request using resharp, however the 'response' is always null, why?

```
private IRestResponse response;
public IRestResponse POSTAsync(string url) {
 IRestResponse response = null;

 client.ExecuteAsync(new RestRequest(url, Method.POST), (r) => {
  if (r.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
  response = r;
 });

 return response;
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're using the old style of asynchronous programming instead of the new Task-based pattern (`await client.ExecuteTaskAsync`)? And are you sure it's a good idea to return an IRestReponse from this interface? That's going to leak implementation details (force use of RestSharp) in other classes that probably don't need to know how you get the response.

Comment: im on VS2012 and using old restsharp lib

Comment: What version of .NET are you using?

Comment: You don't do anything in your code if `r.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK`. That could lead to the response being null. Have you considered logging an error or throwing an exception if the status code isn't OK?

Comment: im using net 4.5

Comment: .NET 4.5 should be able to use the Task-based asynchronous pattern I believe.

Comment: @mason  i think no, https://i.imgur.com/d9Eveg0.jpg

Comment: You can update your RestSharp version. Should be easy. You are using NuGet, right? And did you take a look at my recommendations regarding the status code?

Comment: @mason i cant update by nuget, beacuse vs2012... and i dont found an update binaries... Yes, i will implemente a exception.  Could not install package 'RestSharp 106.3.1'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.

Comment: Can you install RestSharp version 105.2.3?

Answer (score 0):

From what i see, the response will always be null, since you are calling an asynchronous service and you are not waiting for the transaction to end.

```
private IRestResponse response;
public IRestResponse POSTAsync(string url) {
 IRestResponse response = null;

 client.ExecuteAsync(new RestRequest(url, Method.POST), (r) => {
  if (r.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK) // This is going to a new thread and will be executing later
  response = r;                          // eventually this will be called, but your method did not wait for that completition
 });

 return response; // Response will always be null because the Async method is not
                  // finished yet
}
```

So, you should not be using try to use asynchronous methods if your surrounding code does not support it, since in the end you will need to block your method to wait for the result.

That is the reason why, the `async` keyword was created, you need to make all your calls dependent call asynchronous also, and that is the reason why the controllers now support `async` and tasks as return type (As an example from a modern Net Core app):

```
[HttpGet("{msisdn}")]
public Task<string> Get(string msisdn)
{
    return _hubUserProfileService.CallProfileService(msisdn);
}
```

So, update your app so your entire request speaks asynchronous, or just do not use it, since it is not bringing anything to your code, it is even now more heavy, since it has to create the task to call the method in other thread... while the calling method must wait anyway for the response.

To clarify:

Calling asynchronous methods is not magic, you want that for the request to be executed in another thread, yet, immediately after creating that thread, you are hopping to the result to be available, and that is not how asynchronous execution works, you callback will be executed somewhere in the future, you do not know when, that is why the callback method is needed, the method will just create the task and continue, but the task is not executed yet, yo the variable is still null, you could add a `Thread.Sleep()` before the return response to verify what i am saying, this way you could give time for the asynchronous callback to finish, that is why making it asynchronous it is not giving you anything new.

Comment: Can i ask why the downvote? is something that i am missing?

Comment: Just because it's `client.ExecuteAsync` doesn't mean the code is using the Task-based async features of C#. That would be in newer versions of RestSharp, and accessed using the `client.ExecuteTaskAsync` method.

Comment: It was as an example to clarify, it is still valid that in the return the response will be null, no matter the restsharper version since he is setting the value in another thread which has not ended yet. He must wait the task to end, or handle the callbacks in an asynchronous way

Comment: `ExecuteAsync` takes a callback parameter, so the `async` keyword is not necessary. I don't think your answer helps the OP, who is using an ancient version of Visual Studio and RestSharp.

Comment: I am not talking about async as the reserved keyword, i am using it with the meaning that his method is going to be executed in another thread, in another time, the I used the async controller example to clarify that the full path must be prepared to handle the async excecutions, if not, it must be some place were the method has to stop and wait for the results

Comment: If you weren't talking about async as in the reserved word, then why did you surround it with tick marks? I think your answer is just confusing the situation. You might consider rewriting it to either show how to execute this synchronously, or how to use the Task based pattern, including which version of RestSharp is needed.

Comment: Edited my answer to try to clarify, sadly I can not make an example right now with older versions and testing since i am at work, but i hope It can help @Melis, since his error has nothing to do with the resharper version, it has to do with the way he is handling the asynchronous methods